# Angularjs - Editing arrays returned from http get url

Tags: angularjs, url

I have this array I am getting through the following method:

```
      var url= *url defined here*;
      $scope.ViewProfile = function () {
        $http.get(url)
            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.ProfileList = response;
                $scope.FavNumbers = $scope.ProfileList[0].FavNumbers;
             })
            .error(function () {
               });
    }
```

I am required to edit the Fav Numbers list on the UI. and post it back to another url through http post url method. What I am stuck is with the concept of asynchronous calls, due to which I am unable to retrieve the favorite numbers list to be available for editing. Please help!

I have tried a method of using promises as follows:

```
       app.factory('myService', function($http) {
        var myService = {
         async: function(url) {
        var promise = $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          return response.data;
        });
      // Return the promise to the controller
       return promise;
   }
 };

  return myService;
});
```

In my controller I am doing:

```
  angular.module('JuryApp').controller('mycontroller', ['myService', function (myService) {

      myService.async(url).then(function(d) {
     $scope.data = d;
 });

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function( myService,$scope) {
  // Call the async method and then do stuff with what is returned inside      our own then function
    myService.async().then(function(d) {
   $scope.data = d;
   });
 });
```

But I keep getting the error 'd is not defined'. It keeps giving an error of some sort, where the debugger goes into an infinite loop or something.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating it, I think. Async calls are actually pretty simple:

You're service:

```
app.factory("myService", ["$http", function($http) {
  var MyService = {
    getData: function(url) {
      return $http.get(url);  //$http returns a promise by default
    }
  };
  return MyService;
})];
```

Your controller:

```
angular.module('JuryApp').controller('mycontroller', ['myService', function (myService) {
  $scope.FavNumbers = [];
  var url = "http://my.api.com/";
  myService.getData(url).then(function(response) {
    $scope.FavNumbers = response.data[0].FavNumbers;
  });
}]);
```

That's all that you need to do.